# If element of list is present as part of string return the element as new column entry

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a list with a few entires:

```
val list = Seq("Car", "House", "Beach")
```

The data looks like this:

```
val df = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(
("Pete", "He has a Car"),
("Mike", "The Beach is beautiful"),
("Steve", "Look at this House")
)).toDF("Name", "message"
```

What I want to accomplish is an additional column where the value is the element of the list if the element is present within the message column.

```
|----------------------------------|
|Name |Message              |NewCol|
|----------------------------------|
|Pete |He has a Car         |Car   |
|Mike |The Beach is beatiful|Beach |
|Steve|Look at this House   |House |
|----------------------------------|
```

I tried a few things but without any success like

```
a) when($"message".isin(list:_*)
b) A udf with -> list.exists(message.contains(_))
```

I also thought about comparing the string with a regular expression of `*<listelement>*` but could not get that to work either.

A join would also be a possibility(even more wanted) since the list is created by a column of a dataframe. The new column would only be used to join afterwards with the origin df of the list.

```
val new_df = df.join(df_listorigin, Seq("NewCol"))
```

I think right now I am thinking too complicated. Any help or ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: what if there are multiple words in `Message` that are within `list` ?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add this information. This case will never happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UDF-approach:

```
val contains = udf((m:String) => list.filter(m.contains(_)).mkString(","))

df
  .withColumn("NewCol",contains($"message"))
  .show()

+-----+--------------------+------+
| Name|             message|NewCol|
+-----+--------------------+------+
| Pete|        He has a Car|   Car|
| Mike|The Beach is beau...| Beach|
|Steve|  Look at this House| House|
+-----+--------------------+------+
```

Or with a join:

```
df
  .join(list.toDF("NewCol"),$"message".contains($"NewCol"),"left")
  .show()

+-----+--------------------+------+
| Name|             message|NewCol|
+-----+--------------------+------+
| Pete|        He has a Car|   Car|
| Mike|The Beach is beau...| Beach|
|Steve|  Look at this House| House|
+-----+--------------------+------+
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It is as I thougt :D I was going into the wrong direction.
I used the join version you provided. 
One thing to note for future readers: The UDF approach only works if elements of the list consist of only single word elements. The join appraoch also works with multiple word elements (like in my case)